# Как ускорить работу сайта на Битрикс (хостинг Timeweb), если 10 из 14 способов уже опробованы

Tags: битрикс, производительность

Есть сайт на битрикс, хостинг timeweb.ru
Сайт вот с такими показателями:

Имитация загрузки страницы

First Contentful Paint 5,2 сек.
Speed Index 6,1 сек.
Largest Contentful Paint 8,0 сек.
Time to Interactive 7,7 сек.
Total Blocking Time 1 020 мс
Cumulative Layout Shift 0,003

Я уже оптимизировал все большие изображения, сделав их 100 +/-10 кб
Я задействовал все инструменты ускорения Битрикс, кроме переноса загрузки кода CSS и JS вниз страницы (тогда поехал дизайн на некоторых страницах)
Я прописал код LAST-modified в файл init.php

Остальное уже не вспомню, но скорость удалось увеличить с 14 баллов до 26-38 (в зависимости от времени загрузки).

Неужели остается лишь протестить новый хостинг или кардинально изменить дизайн главной страницы сайта, чтобы скорость загрузки увеличилась?

Подскажите, мастера!

Comment: Сайт vorotasuper.ru

Comment: Вы уточните вы гонитесь за виртуальными попугаями производительности битрикса или вы хотите увеличить именно скорость загрузки страницы?
На любом шаред-хостинге вы будете иметь показатель 25-50 попугаев. Гнаться выше 30 на шареде бессмыслено и невозможно. Хотите больше размещайте сайт на  vps или физическом сервере. Там можно добиваться 100-300. Производительность меряет железо, а не скорость загрузки. Скорость там только один из параметров. У вас она 7 секунд. Что в общем-то много.